# get all the postid from a active post on a user

Tags: laravel, foreach

i am new in php and also very new in laravel and i try my self to learn how to fetch post from database thats seems active and posted from user under the table "postmeta"

I am looking to the database and see that, when a post is active it started with the first column like this:

post_id ------meta_key------meta_value

--6323 -------*status*------active

this is the first column where you can see that there is a post,the next column follow columns shows all the information like :

post_id ------   meta_key ------ meta_value

6323 ------     type ------ for home

6323 ------     price ------ free

6323 ------   condetion ------ good

6323 ------   description ------ description blabla

6323 ------    attached ------ image-url

6323 ------ attachment_metadata ------ image-url

6323 ------    attached ------ image-url

6323 ------ attachment_metadata ------ image-url

and so on.

i trying to set foreach 
to find the post thats under the type and look if this active 
if it active i set another if else to fetch the data from the post_id but it didn work

PostmetasController:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class PostmetasController extends Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
      $postmetas = DB::table('postmeta')->get();
      return view('postmeta.index', ['postmetas' => $postmetas]);
  }
}
```

and the model postmetas.php are :

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Postmetas extends Model
{
  public function postmetas()
{
return $this->belongsToMany('App\meta_id');
}
}
}
```

and the php page index.blade.php:

```
<?php
<div class="container">
  <h1>Show this Post Message page</h1>

  @foreach ($postmetas as $postmeta)
    @if($postmeta->meta_value == "active")
    <?php
    $postId = substr($postmeta->post_id, 0, 10);
    ?>

      @if($postId == $postmeta->post_id)
      <br>

        <?php
            echo "this is the String: ";
            echo $postId;
        ?>
        <br>
          this is the id :

        {{ $postmeta->post_id }}

    @endif
    @endif
```

i get this results :

found active post: 33196

this is the next id from the post: 33196

found active post: 33204

this is the next id from the post: 33204

found active post: 14763

this is the next id from the post: 14763

so i can found onlye the next post id 
but there are maybe 10 columns with the same post id 
how can i set the loop to fetch all the other post id also

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Laravel, Try this package for Custom Meta tags like WordPress

https://github.com/plank/laravel-metable

(or)

```php
function getAllMeta($postId){
   return YourModel::where('post_id' , $postId)->all();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to get all rows related to all posts that are active:

```
//all active posts:
$activePosts = DB::table('postmeta')
                  ->where('meta_key', 'status')
                  ->where('meta_value', 'active')->get();
```

By having one postId or all post Ids (that you know are active), then you can obtain all related rows:

```php
//When you have multiple posts:
$postIds = $activePosts->pluck('post_id')->toArray();
$relatedRows = DB::table('postmeta')->whereIn('post_id', $postIds)->get();

//OR when it is only one postId:
$relatedRows = DB::table('postmeta')->where('post_id', $postIds)->get();
```

By the way, postId is supposed to be an integer ID. right?
What is the "$postId = substr($postmeta->post_id, 0, 10)" then?

Comment: this is a wordpress database where all the meta include in 4 rows, and i want just to fetch the the data that belongs to the post from users. like this:


    5695  4959  _cat_ad_status_   active


    5696  4959  _cat_is_feature   0


    5697  4959  _cat_ad_currency   ₺


    5698  4959  _cat_poster_name   Jordan N.


    5699  4959  _cat_poster_contact  05534827910


    5700  4959  _cat_ad_location   kogan street, frankfurt/germany, De...


but under this row there are also other data that is not belong to "_cat_"

Comment: let say there is a active post under the meta_key and it have the id "4959" under the post_id rows then i need to fetch all the post id with this number from the post_id!



sorry but this text menú looks terrible there is no enter space on this add comment box

Comment: only the pictures have a differend post id that is set in post_id 4959  _sb_photo_arrangement_  4960,4961,4962,4963,4964

Comment: By 4 rows, do you mean 4 columns?

Comment: yes @Akhir under the table postmeta there are only 4 rows meta_id - post_id -  -   meta_key   -  meta_value